# How can I play king of the hill on Sanctuary?

Tags: halo-the-master-chief-collection

I've made a custom map in forge based on the Halo 2 anniversary level Sanctuary. I've added several king of the hill markers and have them all unique, incrementing Spawn Sequence numbers. However, when trying to play the map in custom games, my only game type options are slayer, juggernaut, and infection.  When setting the game type to king of the hill before selecting the map, the losing screen flashes before in sent to a blank game over screen.

How can I set up a forge map to offer king of the hill games?